# C# multi tcp server

Tags: c#, server, tcp, client

So i got this multi thread tcp server code, it is working great, but i can not switch between clients.

So my question is how can i switch between clients?
I am planing to switch the server to winforms but i do not know how to access other threads.
Also, please tell what should i improve and better ways of sanitizing user input.
Here is the server code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {
        const int PORT_NO = 5000;
        const string SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //---listen at the specified IP and port no.---
            IPAddress localAdd = IPAddress.Parse(SERVER_IP);
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localAdd, PORT_NO);
            //---prepare client counter---
            int num = 0;
            //---announce and start listening---
            Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
            listener.Start();

            while (true)
            {

                //---incoming client connected---
                TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                new Thread(() =>
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;

                    //---add 1 to total clients---
                    num = num + 1;

                                //---check if current thread name is null, if yes set the current client position---
                    if (Thread.CurrentThread.Name == null)
                    {
                        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = num.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Unable to name a previously " +
                            "named thread.");
                    }

                    string clientip = ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
                    //---write that client connected and write its ip---
                    Console.WriteLine("Client connected: [IP: {0}, Client: {1}]", clientip, Thread.CurrentThread.Name);

                    //---loop for infinite amount of time---
                    while (true)
                {
                        try
                        {
                                //---Make thread background---
                                Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
                                //---get the incoming data through a network stream---
                                NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
                            new Thread(() =>
                            {
                                byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

                                //---read incoming stream---
                                int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

                                //---convert the data received into a string---
                                string dataReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                Console.WriteLine("[IP: {0}, Client: {1}]: " + dataReceived, clientip, Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
                                }).Start();

                                //---write back the text to the client---
                                Console.WriteLine("Enter data to send back to [IP: {0}, Client: {1}]: ", clientip, Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
                                //---read user input---
                                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                                //---sanitize user input---
                                if (input == String.Empty)
                                {
                                    input = @" ";
                                }
                                if (input == @"")
                                {
                                    input = @" ";
                                }
                                if (input == null)
                                {
                                    input = @" ";
                                }
                                //---convert ASCII text to bytes---
                                byte[] send = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
                                //---write bytes to network stream---
                                nwStream.Write(send, 0, send.Length);
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            //---close client---
                            client.Close();
                            //---Announce disconnect---
                            Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected [IP: {0}, Client: {1}]", clientip, Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
                            //---remove 1 from total clients---
                            num = num - 1;
                            //---Abort current thread---
                            Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                }).Start();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        const int PORT_NO = 5000;
        const string SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //---data to send to the server---
            string textToSend = "Received the text.";

            //---create a TCPClient object at the IP and port no.---
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(SERVER_IP, PORT_NO);
            while (true)
            {
                NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textToSend);

            //---send the text---
            Console.WriteLine("Sending : " + textToSend);
            nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

            //---read back the text---
            byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            Console.WriteLine("Received : " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead));

            }
            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thread per client is not scalable. How many clients are you looking at here? Honestly, kestrel is a good way to write a TCP server. Writing it from scratch: really not. Network and threading is *hard*. Really really hard.

Comment: Assuming you want real-time communication between clients, I'd just use SignalR, running inside a webserver that already exists. Like Marc says, don't reinvent the wheel